# Не получается указать русский язык и вывести погоду в pyowm

Tags: python, pyowm

Решил написать простецкий код для погоды и позже перенести в бота, но возникла пробелема ещё в написании основной части. Когда пытаюсь указать русский язык, пишет " _ *init* _() got an unexpected keyword argument 'language'". Если же убрать его, то есть ещё одна проблема в "***print("В городе " + place + " сейчас " + w.get_detailed_status())***". Пишет " 'Weather' object has no attribute 'get_detailed_status'". Если же без "get", то вот "'str' object is not callable"

```
import pyowm
owm = pyowm.OWM('MyToken', language = 'ru')
place = input("В каком городе вы хотите узнать погоду?: ")

mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.weather

temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]

print("В городе " + place + " сейчас " + w.get_detailed_status())
print("Температура в городе " + str(temp) )
print (w)

if temp < 10:
    print("Сейчас холодно. Оденься, как танк!")
elif temp < 20:
    print("Сейчас холодно. Оденься")
else:
    print("Сегодня тепло. Одевайся полегче")



  



https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBQvk.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указать язык можно через словарь конфигурации, который передаётся вторым аргументом в `OWM`.

***Пример:***

```py
from pyowm.owm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'
owm = OWM('MyToken', config_dict)

place = 'Москва'  # input('В каком городе вы хотите узнать погоду?: ')

mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
weather = observation.weather

temp = weather.temperature('celsius')['temp']
status = weather.detailed_status

print(f'В городе {place} сейчас {status}')
print(f'Температура в городе {temp}')

if temp < 10:
    print('Сейчас холодно. Оденься, как танк!')
elif temp < 20:
    print('Сейчас холодно. Оденься')
else:
    print('Сегодня тепло. Одевайся полегче')
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import pyowm

#owm = pyowm.OWM('MyToken', language = 'ru')
owm = pyowm.OWM('7c6d5748acf9.......17c86eMyToken')

place = input("В каком городе вы хотите узнать погоду?: ")

#mgr = owm.weather_manager()
#observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)

#w = observation.weather
w = observation.get_weather()
#temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]
temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]

print(f"В городе {place} сейчас {temp}")      #w.get_detailed_status())
#print("Температура в городе " + str(temp) )
#print (w)

if temp < 10:
    print("Сейчас холодно. Оденься, как танк!")
elif temp < 20:
    print("Сейчас холодно. Оденься")
else:
    print("Сегодня тепло. Одевайся полегче")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

**15/05/2021 - Работающий способ вывода информации на русском языке!!!**

```
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

place = input(" Введите город/страну: ")

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru' 

owm = OWM( 'a99967bc9ee70d5b4bd387902982f400', config_dict  )

mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.weather

reg = owm.city_id_registry()
list_of_locations = reg.locations_for('moscow', country='RU')
moscow = list_of_locations[0]
lat = moscow.lat   # 55.75222
lon = moscow.lon   # 37.615555

temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]
status = w.detailed_status

print("В городе " + place + " сейчас " + str(status))
print("Температура сейчас в районе " + str(temp))

if temp < 10:
    print("\n\nСейчас ппц как холодно, одевайся как танк!")
elif temp < 20:
    print("\n\nСейчас холодно, одевайся потеплее.")
else:
    print("\n\nТемпература норм, одевай что угодно.")
print()
```

[image: Вывод:]